# TypeError : unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python

I am a beginner in python and just for the sake of testing out my skills, tried to make a program to check if a given integer can be expressed as a sum of two prime numbers the code for which I have mentioned below -

```
a = int(input('Enter the number: '))
def prime(b):
    for i in range(2, b):
        while b % i == 0:
            pass
        else:
            return b
if a < 3:
    print("The number is too short to be tested")
else:
    for i in range(2, a):
        for j in range(2, a):
            d = prime(i)
            e = prime(j)
            if d + e == a:
                print("It can be expressed as a sum of prime numbers")
                break
    else:
        print("The number can not be expressed as a sum of prime numbers")
```

The error says `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'`
I understand that the prime class needs to return a value first hence I stored the returned values in variables d and e respectively but in vain. Any help with the above would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What do you expect your function `prime()` to return given its parameter?

Comment: Could you provide the full error traceback?

Comment: `prime` should simply return `True` or `False`, and you can use those results to decide if you want to check that `i + j == a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function `prime` is doing too many things. Just have it return `True` if prime, `False` otherwise.

```
def prime(b):
    for i in range(2, b):
        if b % i == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

You also don't need to iterate over two ranges: just check if `i` and `a - i` are prime (because `i + a - i == a` by definition). Also, since `i` and `a - i` are symmetric around `a/2`, you don't need to iterate over the full range of values from 2 to `a`.

```
a = int(input('Enter the number: '))

if a < 3:
    print("The number is too short to be tested")
else:
    for i in range(2, a // 2 + 1):
        if prime(i) and prime(a - i):
            print("It can be expressed as a sum of prime numbers")
            break
    else:
        print("The number can not be expressed as a sum of prime numbers")
```

As an exercise, adapt the loop so that you don't have to consider *all* values between 2 and `a// 2 + 1`, only 2 and the odd ones.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you return a default value if the statement `b % i == 0` is never statisfied in `prime()`.
Also please verify d and e actually exists before this statement `(d + e) == a`

Example: (should run as is)

```
a = int(input('Enter the number: '))


def prime(b, default=None):
    for i in range(2, b):
        if not b % i == 0:
            return b
    return default


if a < 3:
    print("The number is too short to be tested")
else:
    for i in range(2, a):
        for j in range(2, a):
            d, e = prime(i), prime(j)
            if d and e and (d + e) == a:
                print("It can be expressed as a sum of prime numbers")
                break
    print("The number can not be expressed as a sum of prime numbers")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
a = int(input('Enter the number: '))
def prime(b):
    for i in range(2, b):
        if b % i == 0:
            continue
        else:
            return b
if a < 3:
    print("The number is too short to be tested")
else:
    for i in range(3, a + 1):
        for j in range(3, a + 1):
            d = prime(i)
            e = prime(j)
            if d + e == a:
                print("It can be expressed as a sum of prime numbers")
                break
    else:
        print("The number can not be expressed as a sum of prime numbers")
```

This variation should work

Comment: I have tried your code and I get the same reported error.

Comment: this is because `range(2, a)` produces `2` in the first loop and `prime(2)` is `None`. I've fixed my answer

Comment: Ok, but now when I enter `5`, I get the negative response. I would expect a program like this to know that `2 + 3 = 5`